# Android SurfaceView Bitmap quality is worse than ImageView in XML

Tags: android, xml, image, bitmap, surfaceview

When I draw a bitmap on a SurfaceView by a draw method the image(background in this case) is blurry and bad quality, even though it is not scaled up. When I use the same image as background in an XML layout it looks way better, sharper.

This is the code I use to load a bitmap:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;
    options.inPreferQualityOverSpeed = true;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    bmpLoader = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
    bmpImage= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmpLoader,width, height,true);
    if (bmpLoader!=null){
        bmpLoader.recycle();  
        bmpLoader = null;
        }
```

And also I use a special paint for painting bitmaps:

```
    bitmapPaint = new Paint();
    bitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    bitmapPaint.setDither(true);
    bitmapPaint.setFlags(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    bitmapPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

In case someone has the same problem:
You have to call and set this pixel format

```
    yoursurfaceviewinstance.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

before you set your content view to this surface view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone has the same problem:
You have to call and set this pixel format

```
    yoursurfaceviewinstance.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

before you set your content view to this surface view.